# Operator new and bad_alloc on linux

Tags: c++, linux, new-operator, bad-alloc

On Linux, malloc doesn't necessarily return a null pointer if you're out of memory.  You might get back a pointer and then have the OOM killer start eating processes if you're really out of memory.  Is the same true for c++'s operator new or will you get the bad_alloc exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same is true for operator new, alas :^(

Answer (score 7):

It's a kernel function rather than a language function - and you can control it with the `vm.overcommit_memory` and `vm.overcommit_ratio` sysctls.

They're visible in the proc filesystem at `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio`.

Comment: Not a whole lot the C++ runtime can do when the OS is lying.